Flutter OneSignal migration
I am trying to migrate my OneSignal code in my notifications dart file. But the documentation is not so clear how certain field have changed...
This is my current code that was written with 3.5.0 onesignal_flutter version:
import 'package:onesignal_flutter/onesignal_flutter.dart';

import 'package:hatvan_app/constants/tokens.dart';

Future<void> initOneSignal() async {
  try {
    await OneSignal.shared.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.info, OSLogLevel.none);

    await OneSignal.shared.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_CLIENT_ID);

    await OneSignal.shared
        .promptUserForPushNotificationPermission(fallbackToSettings: false);

    await OneSignal.shared.promptUserForPushNotificationPermission();

    OneSignal.shared
        .setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler((notification) {});
  } catch (e) {
    print("OneSignal init error: ${e.toString()}");
  }
}

Future<String?> get onesignalId =>
    OneSignal.shared.getDeviceState().then((state) {
      final id = state?.userId;
      return id;
    });


I updated the version to 5.2.6 checked out github but the only thing I found how to actually migrate is the setLogLevel as it just simple was moved to Debug:
await OneSignal.Debug.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.info);

I need to migrate everything and .shared is not defined in OneSignal anymore.
